# Blocking pipe ConnectNamedPipe does not trigger

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipe

I want to do IPC using named pipes.
Here is a test client/server that I attempted to make to communicate between two processes
Client code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE pipe = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\pipe\\DokiDoki", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (pipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        char buffer[] = "DokiDoki from the other side :P";
        DWORD bytesWritten;
        WriteFile(pipe, static_cast<LPCVOID>(buffer), sizeof(buffer), &bytesWritten, NULL);
        std::cout << "Done!\n";
        CloseHandle(pipe);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Could not get a handle to the pipe!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\DokiDoki", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, sizeof(buffer), sizeof(buffer), NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, NULL);
    while (pipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (!ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL)) {
         //Setting a breakpoint here will never trigger.
            DWORD bytesRead = 0;    
            while (ReadFile(pipe, static_cast<LPVOID>(buffer), sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
                std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
            }
        }
        DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program stops at ConnectNamedPipe and will not execute any other instructions, even when the client connects and writes to the pipe.
WriteFile (on the client) returns true.

Comment: For which see the [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Reminds me how terrible this API is. `ConnectNamedPipe()` should return a new handle, and you shouldn't have to recreate the pipe or deal with the `fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? 
         TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);` nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

[ConnectNamedPipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-connectnamedpipe?redirectedfrom=MSDN) returns a nonzero value if it succeeds, which is why this wasn't working.
Changing `if (!ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL))` to `if (ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL))` seems to work fine.

Comment: While what you say is true, that is not what you originally claimed. You made it seem the code was **blocked** on `ConnectNamedPipe()`, in which case the return value wouldn't matter one way or another. Unless you misrepresented the problem and actually put the breakpoint AFTER the `ConnectNamedPipe()` and wasn't reaching it since the `if` block wasn't being entered.

Comment: So it didn't stop at `ConnectNamedPipe()` at all. It fell through to the disconnect, which BTW should not be executed on failure.

Comment: This is also not the correct answer. You also have to handle `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED`, as for some reason known only to Microsoft this condition is an error, not a success.. See the MSDN example for details.

Comment: @user207421 - reason for `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` (`STATUS_PIPE_CONNECTED`) is known - it mean that client connect to pipe before server call `ConnectNamedPipe`. also exist else one special case - `STATUS_PIPE_CLOSING` (translated to `ERROR_NO_DATA` win32 code) - mean that client already connected and disconnected (ie close self pipe handle). interesting that really client can and write some data to pipe too - and it can be readed by server (despite error named `ERROR_NO_DATA`)

Comment: @RbMm That;s what it says in the documentation all right, but it explains nothing. The question here is why did they designate a success case as an error? What difference does it make whether the client had connected before or after the call? The server code can proceed either way. TCP `accept()` doesn't make this distinction, and nobody has ever missed it.